# PHP function to get Facebook 'statuses' - 'message' of pagebook pages

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

as asked in the title i wish to know if is possible to get facebook status (only the message) of $fb:page_id.
I need it for a facebook app.

I was trying with this graph:
https://graph.facebook.com/$fb:page_id/statuses/message?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX!XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

thank you

Comment: What happened when you tried that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the PHP SDK, and already have an access token and an initialized $facebook object, you can just call $facebook->api('/me/statuses/').

It would look something like this:

```
<?php
      $config = array(
       'appId' => '<APP-ID>',
       'secret' => '<APP-SECRET>',
      );

      $facebook = new Facebook($config);
      $params['limit'] = 10;
      $statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses','GET', $params);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

function loadFB($fbID){
          $myFBToken="ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE";
          $url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$fbID."/feed?access_token=".$myFBToken."&limit=1";
          $c = curl_init($url);
          curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
          $page = json_decode(curl_exec($c));
          curl_close($c);
          $post=reset($page->data);
For Those Who Enjoy Statuses On Facebook, We're Just Trying To Make New Status And You Can Also Get Latest Statuses From [Facebook Status](http://www.123status.com/).